# Screen jerk and random touches

Tags: touchscreen

I am using lenovo k3 note with updated version marshmelo 6.0. Sometimes it happens like random  touches appearing on my screen and screen jerks many times. I have restarted my phone many a time but it happens several time in a day. I don't know what I should do. I am using this it since 1 year.

Comment: Sounds like defective touch panel? Definitely possible for a low price device like this.

Comment: @AndyYan, I am facing this problem since a few months ago, and I am having a Xperia Z1, any idea besides hardware problem? It definitely is not categorized in `low price device` as you mentioned.

Comment: @HanLim Although they don't fall into the price bracket, Xperias, specifically from Z to Z3, are prone to such hardware problem as well, at least as far as what I've seen in my local forum. Eventually you'll get strips of screen area totally unresponsive.

Comment: @AndyYan thanks for the feedback, is there any solution or maybe can i have the link to the forums you mentioned?

Comment: @HanLim The only surefire way out is to swap out the digitizer or the whole screen. I'm Chinese so it's pointless to show you the forums.

Comment: @once again thanks for advice and solution, and coincidently I am a chinese too LOL. Well its alright if you dont. Thanks for the idea anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your screen and the digitizer are going bad. Maybe there is moisture inside your device. I am no expert but if this is the case try to dry it with hair dryer

Comment: Sorry, but drying with a hair dryer is not really the recommended way (microwave neither) – it might do more harm than help. If there's moisture inside electronic equipment, the recommended procedure of drying it is putting it into a box of rice for several days.

Comment: open it up and put it in a food dehydrator works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have some problem with touch screen in past.

some time on low battery random touch appear and on broken screen phone have same problem.

So if problem is hardware this possibly can help.

So I make some application for hot fix this until you change new screen.

app calls Partial Screen, easy to find on google play
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ich.andre.partialscreen

Hope this can be helpful.

Comment: Could you describe a little further how your app helps to solve the problem?

Comment: Good day

This app can block screen region where random touch appear.
By creating region which intercepts all touch in him.

It have two type of region, auto and manual.
You can see on top of screen two on/off toggle, which activate auto and manual service. two type of region.

Auto analyze run on first launch app and collect all touch and after that make region for blocking.
Region means rect on screen which catch all touch and block it.

In manual your own add region.
I add short video guide.
[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0tpF5fa2_MA&t=2s)